# useradd not working properly

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to do an script that will add *users* by a file, the commands works but create a user with unknown password, so I've removed the password but when he logs, he doesn't log in the terminal that he should, like 
`user@machine:~$` he just log in **$**, that is a old bash interface, my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(cat users) #file with the users
do
useradd $i -g redes2016 -m #creating users in group redes2016 with a home directory
passwd -d $i #deleting user password
chage -d 0 $i #forcing him to change he password at next login (doesn't work)
done
```

Comment: It looks like you want `-G` instead of `-g` (is for specifying the GID of the user's default group, not additional groups he/she is a member of) and you want `-s` to specify the shell. (look at *man useradd* for all options). Further, this questions is probably more proper on the StackExchange sites [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/) or [**ServerFault**](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: thank you man, now has worked properly, but i really want to use `-g`, i want to put them in a already existing group.

Comment: You can do that, but you should not make the *default group* for normal users a group that contains more than `1` user. (unless they are only `ftp` users, etc) Why? Because if the default group for each user is a common group, then by default *every user* of the group can read every file of every user in that group (even `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, etc..) It destroys basic user security. So do *both*, give the user a unique group ***and*** make them members of a common group  `-g unique_for_user -G redes2016`